# android how to drag and drop from dialog to activity

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, dialog

I'm facing this issue:

I have an activity with multiple layouts and images that I can drag and drop from one layout to another,
In case there are many images in one layout I can't show all of them in this layout and i'm using a cluster (that contains the number of images in this layout).
Now I want to implement a dialog which will be opened when the cluster is clicked and in this dialog I'll show the images of this layout (So far so good).

The problem is I'm not sure how to drag image from this dialog to the other layouts, What I have in mind is this scenario:

I will be able to drag the image from the dialog - when it 'leaves' the dialog borders the dialog will be closed, but the dragging will be continue, and after that I'll just drop the dragged image to one of the layouts in the activity.

Is it possible to drag image from layout in dialog (...popup or something similar) and drop it on layout inside the activity (which opened the dialog)?

Or maybe there is an option to add a layout to the activity (which will act as dialog but won't put the activity behind it (like floating view).